# Type error problem with django, apache and mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, decimal, mod-wsgi

I've this problem with my django code.

```
TypeError at /conto/partitario/cerca/

unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Decimal' and 'Decimal'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://myurl.com/cerca/
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Decimal' and 'Decimal'
```

On my pc this error has never presented but on production server i've this error frequently on the same page.
On the server if i reload or restart apache the error disappear for 3/4 hours and then come back!!!

Any Idea??

Thanks!

Comment: What database are you using on the server?  What database are you using on your PC?  I'll bet that you did testing in SQLite and you're running under Apache with a different database.

Comment: maybe you store data in cache? and there are some issues when restored?

Comment: sqlite3 on server and on my pc - no cache system at the moment! thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some research i find a tip on this ticket http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10933 and i apply this patch. For four days my software goes fine but yesterday the error come back!!!
Here my code:
movim =

```
conto.movimentocont_set.filter(testata__data_registrazione__lte=data2,testata__data_registrazione__gte=data1).order_by('testata__data_registrazione')

                for mov in movim:

                    dare = dn(dare)  + dn(mov.dare)<----- error on this line????
```